# ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent)

Tags: java, android, json, http-get

As far as I can tell my app looks done and while its not bullet proof it should do the job for testing, but problem is when I build I get these errors.

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1573    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1667 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 935   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3691    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 847  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 605 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Here is my code `Main.java`

```
package bitcoin.Virwox;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

//Variables
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(null);
JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject();
int BTCSell;
int GBPBuy;
int Ammount;
int BTCSLLAmmount;
int GBPSLLAmmount;
int Total;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
}


public void Start(View view) {
    dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

    Ammount = Integer.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.Amountinputtxt).toString());
    GetInfo();
    Process();

    dialog.hide();
}

public void GetInfo() {
    try {
        BestBuySell();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.VirwoxFeeChk);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        ProcessEstimates();
        Total = GBPSLLAmmount; 
    }
    else {
            int holder;
            holder = BTCSell*Ammount;
            Total = (int)(holder/GBPBuy);
    }

}

private void ProcessEstimates() {
    try {
        BTCSLL();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        GBPSLL();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
public void BTCSLL() throws Exception{
    //retrieve data for BTC>SLL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String http = "http://api.virwox.com/api/json.php?method=estimateMarketOrder&amount="+Ammount+"&orderType=SELL&instrument=BTC/SLL";     
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(http);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024] ;
        InputStream is = entity.getContent() ;
        int numBytes = is.read(buffer) ;
        is.close();

        String entityContents = new String(buffer,0,numBytes) ;
        Log.d("xxx",entityContents);

        try {
            jArray = new JSONObject(entityContents);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{}
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{}

    //Parse Data
    JSONArray  result = jArray.getJSONArray("result");
    //parse BTC>SLL
    JSONObject f = result.getJSONObject(0);
    BTCSLLAmmount = Integer.parseInt(f.getString("amount"));
}
public void GBPSLL() throws JSONException{
//retrieve data for SLL>GBP
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String http = "http://api.virwox.com/api/json.php?method=estimateMarketOrder&amount="+BTCSLLAmmount+"&orderType=BUY&instrument=SLL/GBP";        
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(http);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024] ;
    InputStream is = entity.getContent() ;
    int numBytes = is.read(buffer) ;
    is.close();

    String entityContents = new String(buffer,0,numBytes) ;
    Log.d("xxx",entityContents);

    try {
        jArray = new JSONObject(entityContents);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{}
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{}

//Parse Data
JSONArray result = jArray.getJSONArray("result");
//parse BTC>SLL
JSONObject e2 = result.getJSONObject(0);
GBPSLLAmmount = Integer.parseInt(e2.getString("amount"));
}

public void Process() {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.PaypalFeeChk);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {            
        Total = Total - 1; 
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Outputtxt);
    tv.setText("Total: £" + Total + ".00");

    CurrentRate();
}

public void CurrentRate(){
    float holder;
    holder = BTCSell/GBPBuy;
    BigDecimal payment = new BigDecimal(holder);
    NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK); 
    double doublePayment = payment.doubleValue();
    String s = n.format(doublePayment);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentRatetxt);
    tv.setText(s);
}

public void BestBuySell() throws Exception, IOException{
    //retrieve data
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://api.virwox.com/api/json.php?method=getBestPrices&symbols[0]=BTC/SLL&symbols[1]=GBP/SLL");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024] ;
        InputStream is = entity.getContent() ;
        int numBytes = is.read(buffer) ;
        is.close();

        String entityContents = new String(buffer,0,numBytes) ;
        Log.d("xxx",entityContents);

        try {
            jArray = new JSONObject(entityContents);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{}
    }
    finally{}   
    //parse info
    JSONArray  result = jArray.getJSONArray("result");
    //parse BTC>SLL
    JSONObject e = result.getJSONObject(0);
    BTCSell = Integer.parseInt(e.getString("bestBuyPrice"));
    //Parse SLL>GBP
    e = result.getJSONObject(1);
    GBPBuy = Integer.parseInt(e.getString("bestSellPrice"));
}
}
```

Here's the Layout `Main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/widget43" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:text="BTC-&gt;GBP" android:textSize="45sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="78px" android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="20dip" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/Title"></TextView>
<Button android:layout_width="350px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="42dip" android:layout_y="298dip" android:text="Calculate" android:id="@+id/Button"></Button>
<TextView android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="14dip" android:layout_y="388dip" android:text="Current Exchange rate: " android:id="@+id/Ratetxt"></TextView>
<CheckBox android:checked="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="148dip" android:layout_x="190dip" android:text="Paypal Fee" android:id="@+id/PaypalFeeChk"></CheckBox>
<CheckBox android:checked="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="190dip" android:layout_y="106dip" android:text="Virwox Fees" android:id="@+id/VirwoxFeeChk"></CheckBox>
<TextView android:layout_x="182dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="388dip" android:textSize="15sp" android:id="@+id/CurrentRatetxt" android:text="£0.00"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="245dip" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="18sp" android:id="@+id/Outputtxt" android:text="£0.00" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
<EditText android:text="EditText" android:layout_width="200px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="48dip" android:layout_y="126dip" android:numeric="integer" android:id="@+id/Amountinputtxt"></EditText>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare Context variable before onCreate method:

```
Context thisContext = this;             

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Then when you declare:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisContext);
```

Use the context variable.

Don't use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting it's caused by this line;

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(null);
```

And I would recommend to move initiating it to e.g `onCreate(...)` instead;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);   
}
```

Comment: thanks ^^ did the trick now to debug the thing since i can load it lol